# First Differentatior and Integrator

Tags: filters, digital-filters, time-series

For discrete time series $Y$, first differentiation ($D_i=Y_i-Y_{i+1}$) and integrator ($S_i=Y_i+Y_{i+1}$) can be defined as two highpass and lowpass LTI digital filters. Where, transfer function for the first difference is:
$$
H(z)=1-z^{-1}
$$
and for the first integrator is:
$$
H(z)=1+z^{-1}
$$
These two transfer function corresponds to $\text{Conv}(Y,[1,-1])$ and $\text{Conv}(Y,[1,1])$ for differentiator and integrator, respectively.

I was wondering what the *power transfer function* of these two filters should be.

I have to add, in terms of implementation in Matlab, I can get $S_i$ and $D_i$ of a white noise by:

`Y = randn(1,100); 
D = diff(Y); 
S = Y(1:end-1)+Y(2:end);`

By `filter` in Matlab:

`S_Filt = filter([1  1],1,Y); 
D_Filt = filter([1 -1],1,Y);`

Or by convolving `conv` the corresponding windows:

`S_Conv = conv(Y,[1  1]);
D_Conv  = conv(Y,[1 -1]);`

Note, all `D*` and `S*` variables should be identical (regardless of head and tail of time series, of course).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your integrator expression does not seem to really be an integrator to me, as its finite difference equation is $y[n] = x[n] + x[n-1]$.  Perhaps you wanted $H(z) = \dfrac{1}{1-z^{-1}}$ which has the finite difference equation $y[n] = y[n-1] + x[n]$?  What do you mean by "power transform function"?

Comment: Thanks @AndyWalls. However, when I implement the transfer function you mentioned in Matlab I don't get the S_i. For Y~N(0,1), your transfer function is implemented as filter(1,[1 1],Y) while the S_i is only obtained via filter([1 1],1,Y) which is H(z)=1+z^-1. 
I meant 'power transfer function' which, apparently, is the absolute (modulus) of the transfer function.

Comment: `Y=randn(1,100);

D=diff(Y);
S=Y(1:end-1)+Y(2:end);`

and their equivalent filter is 

`S_Filt=filter([1  1],1,Y); 
D_Filt=filter([1 -1],1,Y);`

Comment: Perhaps, you should check your expression for integration using the line Y=X as a test case, instead of noise. `x=[-4:0.1:4]; y=x; d=diff(y); s = zeros(1,length(y)); s(1)=y(1); for i=[2:length(y)]; s(i)=s(i-1)+y(i); end; plot(x,s); ` Generating s like that, gives me a parabola, as expected.

Answer (score 1):

I think I found an answer to this question. So, I will post it here.

For power transfer function of $1-z^{-1}$ we know:
\begin{eqnarray*}
1-z^{-1}&=&1-e^{-jw}\\
&=& 1-\cos(\omega)+j\sin(w)
\end{eqnarray*}
Then by using complex conjugate properties we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
|1-z^{-1}|^2&=&1-2\cos(\omega)+\cos(\omega)^2+\sin(\omega)^2\\
&=&2(1-\cos(\omega)).
\end{eqnarray*}
And simillarly, for $1+z^{-1}$, we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
|1+z^{-1}|^2&=& 1+2\cos(\omega)+\cos(\omega)^2+\sin(\omega)^2\\
&=& 2(1+\cos(\omega)).
\end{eqnarray*}

-

Note that the integrator in this question is a special case (see the expression for $S_i$) and is different than the conventional integrator $y[n]=y[n-1]+x[n]$.